# Find entries from jsonb by key and value with using java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

How can I get entries that contain a specific key and value in a `jsonb` column?
For example I need to get entry containing `classifiedId` = `665`.

This is an example of my `jsonb` column with name `external_ids`:

```json
{
  "bookId": "36056",
  "keyId": "662123",
  "classifiedId": "665"
}
```

My java code:

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = """
        select *
        from _book_complex
        where jsonb_exists(external_ids, ?1)
    """)
Optional<BookComplexEntity> findByClassifiedId(String classifiedId);
```

But it does not work correctly and does not find the entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is the best solution, but it worked:

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = """
        select *
        from _book_complex ap
        where ap.external_ids ->> 'classifiedId' = ?1
    """)
Optional<BookComplexEntity> findByClassifiedId(String classifiedId);
```